# Show that this set $\{a_n\in\mathbb{R} : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ has lebesgue measure zero.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

Since $a_n$ is countable, it cannot be an interval in $\mathbb{R}$ and hence the infimum of the cover of this set will have volume zero.

Is this good enough reasoning?

Comment: Just saying the set is not an interval is not enough (or even that the set contains no interval).  For example, the set of irrational numbers in $[0,1]$ contains no interval but has Lebesgue measure $1$.

Comment: The Lebesgue measure is countably additive, so all you need to show is that the singleton is of Lebesgue measure zero.

Comment: @yousufsoliman, thanks, that is easier

Comment: @paw88789 Thanks, this insight was very helpful

Comment: Or you could show that for any $\epsilon>0$, you can find a collection of intervals of total length $\epsilon$ that covers your set.